# Having error when pushing global linked list *sometimes(randomly)*

Tags: c

I created a global linked list. It doesnt work sometimes. First push is always succesfully done but second push makes error sometimes. I tried on another computer but its same.

```
typedef struct person{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char musical_Work[20];
    int age;
    struct person *next;
}*top;

top head=NULL;  /* GLOBAL */

void addNode(   /* datas */    ){  
    top new_node=(top)malloc(sizeof(top));

    /* copying datas */

    new_node->next=head;
    head=new_node;  
}
```

Comment: Print `sizeof(top)` and `sizeof(person)`, then decide which value you want to use. You need to alloc memory for person instance, not 4/8 bytes i.e. size of pointer.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks a lot! I just wonder that if i use "top" instead of "*top", is it ok?

Comment: @BerkP. No, you cannot use `*top` because `top` is alias of type `struct person *` and not a variable.

Comment: @rafix07: This is tagged C, and there is no `typedef` for `person`, so `sizeof(person)` is not correct; it should be `sizeof(struct person)`. But better yet would be `malloc(sizeof *new_node)`, as that allocates space for the object being allocated, even if the type of `new_node` is later changed during editing of the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yea, you are completely right, my comment was not precise enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `top new_node=(top)malloc(sizeof(top));` allocates enough space for a `top`, which is a pointer to `struct person`. However, the space is going to be used to hold `struct person`, and therefore it must allocate enough space for `struct person`. Therefore, correct code for this is:

```
 top new_node=(top)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
```

Additionally:

- Using `sizeof *new_node` automatically allocates enough space for whatever new_node points to, even if the type of `new_node` is changed as the code is edited.
- In C, there is no need to cast the type of `malloc`. This code can be `top new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);`.
- Consider using a different name for a pointer to `struct person`, instead of `top`. It is not always the top of the stack.